# Single slideToggle() for the same elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, forum, mybb

I have this code HTML:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <button class="btn-slide"><span class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have several such elements in my forum template. I use standard js toggle() script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('btn-slide').click(function() {
        $('.block').slideToggle(50);
    });
});
```

And when I click on button all components show or hide but I want to hide/show only this element which I choose. I thought that I can use **$(this).childern** in 3rd line but if you see *.block* isn't a *btn-slide* childern. So how can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents)** **[`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-slide').click(function() {
    $(this)
      // get all div in parent level
      .parents('div')
      // get immediate sibling with class block after the element 
      .next('.block')
      .slideToggle(50);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn-slide"><span class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    ...
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <button class="btn-slide">
          <span class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, it's helpful but what if I have another div structure? Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/t7reu8d1/ ?

Answer (score 0):

change your js with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn-slide').click(function() {
    $(this.nextSibling.parentNode.nextElementSibling).slideToggle(50);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you can add another unique class to `block` like `block-new` and use toggle event to that class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn-slide').click(function() {
        $('.block-new').slideToggle(50);
    });
});
```

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dhananjaymane11/t7reu8d1/1/